# How to model DAO in UML

Tags: java, uml, dao

I need some help with UML modeling, I have the follow DAO Class named `ResumeDAO` that NOT have variable types of `User`, BUT, it have methods which uses `User` as a parameter or a return type, I have to model it explicity as an aggregation? If yes, how can I draw it on my UML diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two have no association (i.e. some attribute referring the other) but just using the other in parameters you have a simple dependency. So you have

```
ResumeDAO - - > User
```